# If $R$ is a ring such that $x^2=x$ $\forall x \in R$ and $I$ is a prime ideal. Show that $R/I$ has two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If $R$ is a ring such that $x^2=x$ $\forall x \in R$ and $I$ is a prime ideal. Show that $R/I$ has two elements.

$R/I = \{ r+I:r\in R \}$

Let $a \in R$

if $a\in I$ then $a+I = 0+I=I$.

if $a\notin I$. We know that $a^2=a$ then $a^2-a=a(a-1)=0 \in I$ since $I$ is an ideal, it is a subgroup under addition. It must contain $0$. As $a\notin I$ then $a-1 \in I$ because $I$ is a prime ideal

this implies that $a+I = 1+I$ 
so $$R/I = \{ I,1+I \}$$

what do you think, is it correct?...If it's not. How would you do it?

Comment: That’s it. There’s nothing else to say.

Comment: Have a little faith in yourself. I'm having a hard time seeing what could possibly make you worried that this argument has a problem, or if it could be simpler.  This is a good candidate for something you could ask in chat to verify.